# Finding a string literal parameter for a specified function

Tags: c#, regex

I have a static class called DataHelper. It has a few methods, but all of them take a string literal (a stored procedure name) as a parameter, like so:

```
DataHelper.ExecuteProc("DBMaster.DatabaseConnections_SelectAll", null, CONN);
```

I would like lo go through a source file and extract the string portion of each of these calls.
I am currently using:

```
DataHelper.*(?<=")(?:[^"]|"")*(?=")
```

but that matches the whole thing. Is there a way via regex to just get the string portion of the parameter list for this function?

Comment: What is the expected result? What kind of values can you expect inside? What is the code you are using? BTW, check [this demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3a%5cG%28%3f!%5e%29%7c%28%3f%3c%3dDataHelper%5c.%5cw%2b%5c%28%29%29%28%3f%3a%5cs*%28%3f%3a%2c%5cs*%29%3f%28%22%5b%5e%22%5c%5c%5d*%28%3f%3a%5c%5c.%5b%5e%22%5c%5c%5d*%29*%22%7c%5b%5e%2c%5cs%29%5d%2b%29%2b%29&i=DataHelper.ExecuteProc%28%22DBMaster.DatabaseConnections_SelectAll%22%2c+null%2c+CONN%29%3b).

Comment: The string portion: "DBMaster.DatabaseConnections_SelectAll"

Comment: Try `(?<=DataHelper\.ExecuteProc\(")[^\\"]*(?:\\.[^\\"]*)*`. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/i3AgFx/1

Comment: Use [`(?<=DataHelper\.\w+\(\s*")[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3dDataHelper%5c.%5cw%2b%5c%28%5cs*%22%29%5b%5e%22%5c%5c%5d*%28%3f%3a%5c%5c.%5b%5e%22%5c%5c%5d*%29*&i=DataHelper.ExecuteProc%28%22DBMaster.DatabaseConnections_SelectAll%22%2c+null%2c+CONN%29%3b)

Comment: Did my suggestion work?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a capturing group or to not have `DataHelper.ExecuteProc` in matching result put it in lookbehind:

```
(?<=DataHelper\.ExecuteProc\(")[^\\"]*(?:\\.[^\\"]*)*
```

See live [demo here](https://regex101.com/r/i3AgFx/1)

Breakdown:

- `(?<=` Start of positive lookbehind

  - `DataHelper\.ExecuteProc\("` Match it but not consume it
- `)` End of lookbehind
- `[^\\"]*(?:\\.[^\\"]*)*` Match string enclosed in double qoutation marks

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
var pattern = "\bDataHelper\..+?\(\"(?<procedure>[^\"]*?)\"";
var result = Regex.Match(input, pattern).Cast<Match>().Select(x=> x.Groups["procedure"].Value).ToList();
```